# Button not visible inside Linear Layout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have this `vehicle_list_fragment_layout.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Layout per il fragment VehicleListFragment. -->
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include layout="@layout/recycler_view_fragment_layout"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnAddVehicle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="+"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

which is used by my `VehicleListFragment` in this way:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.vehicle_list_fragment_layout, container, false);
    btnStartActivity = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnAddVehicle);
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());

    setRecyclerViewLayoutManager(LayoutManagerType.LINEAR_LAYOUT_MANAGER);
    initAdapter();
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    setButtonClickListener();

    return rootView;
}
```

The problem is that the `RecyclerView` is shown correctly, but my `btnAddVehicle` is not shown.

This is `activity_vehicle_layout.xml`, the layout of the `Activity` which hosts my `VehicleListFragment`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="clyky.cartracker.activities.VehicleActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/vehicleContainer">
    </FrameLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I use `vehicleContainer` as container for my fragment.
Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

this is my `recycler_view_fragment_layout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Layout per un fragment che contiene una RecyclerView -->
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Your button is under `recycler_view_fragment_layout` layout.

Comment: @Stanojkovic I don't think so: I've wrapped my `vehicle_list_fragment_layout` with a `ScrollView` and my button isn't shown yet

Comment: Check your `ScrollView` height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. Basicall add weightsum to parent view and layout_weight to their child like i added in below,

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><!-- Layout per il fragment VehicleListFragment. -->
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_weight=".8"
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnAddVehicle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".2"
        android:text="+" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Need to add Orientation to parent as well to show recycler view and button vertically

Comment: thanks for your answer, but your solution doesn't work, my button is still invisible

Comment: post your recycler_view_fragment_layout

Comment: thank you very much, now it works. but if I want to use the `include` tag, how could I do?

Comment: @Clyky, please try my updated answer, it uses the `include` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in `vehicle_list_fragment_layout.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Layout per il fragment VehicleListFragment. -->
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        layout="@layout/recycler_view_fragment_layout"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnAddVehicle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="+"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

and in `recycler_view_fragment_layout.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Layout per un fragment che contiene una RecyclerView -->
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:layout_height="match_parent"
>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: `layout_weight` cannot be applied to `include` tag

Comment: I edited my answer, the idea stays the same, adding a weight of 1 to the included layout. In the included layout, `android:layout_height="0dp"` is useful for performance and `tools:layout_height="match_parent"` allows you to see the rendering of your layout in the editor.

Comment: thank you, I've tried your solution, but it still doesn't work, the button is not visible